# Fetch valid value for a field when one type has two groups with null value and valid value

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have a table as below:

```
ID  Amt type            accnum  rcnum   amt
1   Recovery type 1                 [NULL]  45
1   Total recovery                  [NULL]  34
1   Current Type 1      2345        123     23
1   Total current type              [NULL]  12
1   Current type 1                  [NULL]  78
1   Current rvrsl                   [NULL]  -908
```

Now I want to create this as below where this sums up the amt of each type but will populate valid value if exists else NULL/blank will be populated:

```
ID  Amt type            accnum  rcnum   amt
1   Recovery type 1                 [NULL]  45
1   Total recovery                  [NULL]  34
1   Current Type 1      2345        123     101
1   Total current type              [NULL]  12
1   Current rvrsl                   [NULL]  -908
```

I'm trying to do a left join, but I'm not sure how I will achieve this without dropping other records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like aggregation:

```
select id, amt_type, accnum, max(rcnum), sum(amt)
from t
group by id, amt_type, accnum;
```

Aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.